Can I connect 0V between 2x 24V Power supply in different devices?
Devices:

Robot (24VDC 10A power source, used for an IPC, sensors, electronic boards, CAN communication, DI/DO etc)
Mini automation (24VDC 10A power source but different brand, used for a mini Siemens PLC, sensors, DI/DO etc)

I need to exchange 4 DI/DO 24V signals between the 2 devices, and just connected the 0V of the two power supplies together and didn't use any interface relays - so far it is working ok, without problems.
Is there any danger if I leave the setup like above?
Power Source:
!(https://imgur.com/hTpxuzf)
Devices Diagram:
!(https://imgur.com/a/QKw4PPB)

Please provide a block diagram and or a schematic, your question is unclear

Welcome! Sounds straight-forward, but the devil's in the details. Can you add a block diagram of your setup?

If both power supplies earth the output negative, they may already be connected through Earth

Thank you @bobflux for your reply, great insight. I attached a PS diagram, but it doesn't seem that the earth output the negative (0VDC) unfortunately.

Well if they are isolated from Earth, there is no problem in connecting the negatives either, since no significant current will flow, only leakage from the EMI caps... so it's fine... Related but different question: when using two power supplies like that, if one is powered and the other is not, and the gear from the powered side sends signals to the unpowered gear, you should check the inputs can tolerate voltage when the device is unpowered. Normally industrial gear will just be fine, but if you use DIY boards or arduinos it can't hurt to check.

I attached a link to the Devices diagram too, the green line is the 0V connection between PS1 and PS2. This was done to avoid using interface relays when exchanging 24VDC DI/DO between PLC1 and PLC2

Thank you again bobflux for your replay and warning notices. Everything is industrial gear and seems to work fine.
